# Locate image for use?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm really new to Python, and I never learned this one thing: how do you find an image without a long line of code panning your working directory or a set directory? Here's an example.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
```

The code would open "ball.bmp", but how do I make something that knows where ball.bmp is that's as simple as that code? I've seen it in some scratch examples working, but I just dont know how it's finding the image nor how to re-create it.

Comment: In this example code, `ball.bmp` has to be in the current working directory. It's just like when you're in the DOS box/Terminal, and you can `cat myfile.txt` if it's in the current directory, but not if it isn't.

Comment: In a toy application, you can assume the current working directory is the same directory the script is in, or you can even enforce that with `chdir`. In a real application, you'll probably want to use something like setuptools resources to get your files installed to specific places, and to give you an API to access those places.

Answer (score 1):

For "non toy" applications, there is a pattern used in Python code to findout assets relative to the current running file.

Python modules, when running, have the  `__file__` variable - whcih points ot the file containing the current module.  So, if you get the directory out of `__file__`, you can have absolute paths to your assets:

```
import os
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

image_file = os.path.join(here, "ball.png") # Please don't use bmp  :-)
```

Also, if you are using Python 3.6 and up, you can use `pathlib.Path` instead of the lenghty `os.path` calls:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

here = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))

image_file = here / "ball.png"
```

(`Path` overrides the "/" operator so that it yields "path objects" - these can be used anywere a string containing a Path can, plus take care of some edge cases relating to filesystem upper/lower case normalization,
symbolic links, the fact that '\' used as a directory separator in Windows is also a character used in escape sequences and so on).

Finally - in bigger projects, you can use this technique to set project-wide variables pointing to asset directories. On the project's `__init__` file you could do:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

here = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))

asset_dir = here / "assets"
image_dir = asset_dir / "images"
sound_dir = asset_dir / "sounds"

...
# and, in other file: 
from projectname import image_dir
...
def myfunc(...):
     ...
     image = pygame.image.load(image_dir / "spritename.png")
```

Comment: On a not directly related note, check https://hackernoon.com/the-one-stop-guide-to-easy-cross-platform-python-freezing-part-1-c53e66556a0a  - the Pyinstaler bundler explained there is compatible with the technique described here, allowing you to bundle your games in a single file.